# Transient RL circuit analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis, inductor, resistance, passive-networks, transient

Can anybody help me with the transient analysis problem? I tried to solve and here are my results:I(t)= 2-e^(-2.5t) A
i1(t)=i2(t)=I(t)/2 =(2-e^(-2.5t))/2
=1-0.5e^(-2.5t). but if you observe the circuit,  i2(0-)=i2(0+)=0 and i2(∞)=1A and i1(0+)=i1(0-)=i1(∞)=1A. The calculated equations of i1(t) and i2(t) doesn't satisfy the values.
Now, applying kvl, I got,
10= 2di/dt + 10 i1
I=i1+i2
And i1=i2

Where am I wrong here?
[image]

Comment: Please show us all of your work and explain your thinking along the way. We don't just hand out homework/exam solutions here but if you show a significant effort and ask a specific question we will give you a hint.

Comment: This is just a first order equation (arrived at by first placing the two resistors in parallel) with one non-zero initial condition, which itself is easy to work out. Are you unable to apply the method of integrating factors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumptions about \$I_1\$ and \$I_2\$ are not correct. The current through an **inductor** must be continuous, but these currents are through resistors and there is no inherent requirement that \$i_R(0+)=i_R(0-)\$.

Comment: All I am getting is I(t)= 2- e^(-2.5t) A
And at steady state , I1(t)=I2(t) and I(t)=I1+I2
Then I1(t)=I2(t)= 1- 0.5e^(-2.5t)

Comment: What exactly is your question? What makes you think your answer is incorrect?

Comment: Actually I am a newbie in circuit analysis, so I was a bit confused about my answer...anyway thank you for assisting me